# Navigation log dump

Tags: logging, web, navigation, bigdata, analysis

For an university project, I need a lot of data to analyse (big data stuff). Teacher asked us to try to analyse the log traffic of users, to see the site they visit and the most visited etc. I just need their IP and website the visited. Do you think I can find something like that free on the web? Are there some package containing this kind of information (of course, LEGALLY)?

Comment: Do you need this specific type of big data set or can it be something else?